# CreateStreamOnHGlobal on html resource cause heap corruption

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi

I have a html file added as resource in microsoft visual studio project. I am planning to change the content of it dynamically in my program and use res://webapp.exe/IDR_HTML to navigate to it so it won't be in the file system. I did the following. But CreateStreamOnHGlobal causing a heap corruption. What did I do wrong? Can the html resouce can be modifiied this way at all? I don't have problem if I GlobalAlloc myself and CreateStreamOnHGlobal on it in my program.

```
//problem code
    // Load current module.
    HMODULE hExe = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (hExe == NULL)
    {
        ATLTRACE2(TEXT("Could not load exe."));
        return -1;
    }


    // Locate the html resource in the .EXE file.
    HRSRC hRes = FindResource(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_HTML), RT_HTML);
    if (hRes == NULL)
    {
        ATLTRACE2(TEXT("Could not locate dialog box."));
        return -1;
    }

    // Load the html into global memory.
    HGLOBAL hResLoad = LoadResource(hExe, hRes);
    if (hResLoad == NULL)
    {
        ATLTRACE2(TEXT("Could not load html."));
        return -1;
    }

    CComPtr<IStream> spStream;
    HRESULT hr = ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal( hResLoad, TRUE, &spStream );

//heap error displayed 
HEAP[WebApp.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlGetUserInfoHeap( 00560000, 012844C8 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in WebApp.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in WebApp.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while WebApp.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

//this is fine 
char *acTemp;
    char *acXml = "Hello";
    SIZE_T dwBytes = 256;
    CComPtr<IStream> pDataStream;
    acTemp = (CHAR *) GlobalAlloc (GMEM_FIXED, dwBytes);
    memcpy (acTemp, acXml, dwBytes);
    HRESULT hhr = ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(acTemp, TRUE, &pDataStream);
```

Comment: The HGLOBAL returned by LoadResource not a true HGLOBAL. This is documented as the very first remark. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Raymond Chen said, the `HGLOBAL` returned by `LoadResource()` is not a real `HGLOBAL`, so you cannot pass it to `CreateStreamOnHGlobal()`.  You will have to make a copy of the data in memory, eg:

```
CComPtr<IStream> spStream;
HRESULT hr;

HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, SizeofResource(hResLoad));
if (!hMem)
{
    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}
else
{
    LPVOID ptr = GlobalLock(hMem);
    if (ptr)
    {
        memcpy( ptr, LockResource(hResLoad), SizeofResource(hResLoad) );
        GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    }

    hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal( hMem, TRUE, &spStream );
}
```

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggests, you should consider using [`SHCreateMemStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead, eg:

```
CComPtr<IStream> spStream = ::SHCreateMemStream( (LPBYTE) LockResource(hResLoad), SizeofResource(hResLoad) );
```

Comment: But if I do the way you suggested, the memory is not the same memory that the resource html point to and if I modify the memory the original resource file won't change. My goal is dynamically change the html resource before navigate to it.  Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: Using `SHCreateMemStream()`, the `IStream` would be pointing at the resource memory directly, unlike `CreateStreamOnHGlobal()` which requires a copy. However, you **cannot** modify the contents of a resource while your app is running. Resources are read-only. The only way to modify a resource is to use [`UpdateResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049.aspx) from another process while your app is not running.

Comment: This is the wrong approach to take, though. What you should do instead is either 1) make a copy of the HTML in memory and then modify it as needed before loading it into the browser, or else 2) load the HTML as-is into the browser and then use the browser's DOM interfaces to manipulate the HTML as needed. Either way, changes to the HTML are not persistent, so you should save the modified HTML to a file instead of back to the original resource. When loading the HTML, load the file first, and if that fails then load the resource.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I want is Navigate to an in memory html. So there won't be a html in the file system. Can your approach 1) do this? If it does, how can I load an in memory html into the browser control? Thanks.

Comment: You can navigate the browser to `about:blank` and then use the browser's `IPersistStreamInit` interface to load HTML from any `IStream`. Or, you can simply navigate the browser to a `res://filename.ext[/resource_type]/{res_id}` URL that specifies your app's .exe name and resource ID, and then the browser will load the resource directly without needing any `IStream` at all.  There is an example of a custom HTML resource URL at the bottom of [this document](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27843#pluggable).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will read it later. Meanwhile, the res:// way you proposed is the way I was doing earlier and having trouble with. The problem is html is not static, I need to inject some java script later. As you mention earlier the resource html can't be modified within the application, so I shouldn't use this approach, correct? Thanks.

Comment: Correct. Either copy the HTML into a separate writable memory block and modify it as needed before then loading it, or else load the HTML as-is and use the browser's DOM to modify the HTML inside of the browser itself.